# Вопрос по позиционированию css/js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Насколько я знаю свойство `position: fixed` позиционируется относительно объекта window то есть окна браузера. Вопрос в следующем: как можно спозиционировать элемент таким образом чтобы он был будто fixed относительно нужного блока на странице (допустим колонки сайдбара).
Знаю такой баг - если у нужного контейнера поиграться с `transform: translate;` и дочернему элементу этого контейнера дать `position: fixed` то позиционироваться он будет будто у него `position: absolute`. Но мне нужно чтобы это была такая себе иммитация fixed, чтобы элемент был в рамках `viewport` пока он над ним.

Заранее прошу прощения что так сумбурно объяснил суть вопроса, но лучше сформулировать пока что не могу.

Comment: Лучше всего выносить в разметке в отдельное место.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var outer = $('.outer'),
    inner = $('.inner');
  //console.log(outer.offset().top, $(window).scrollTop());
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= outer.offset().top && $(window).scrollTop() <= outer.offset().top + outer.height() - inner.height()) {
    inner.css('top', $(window).scrollTop() - outer.offset().top)
    console.log($(window).scrollTop(), outer.offset().top)
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < outer.offset().top) {

    inner.css('top', 0)
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  padding: 250px 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 500px;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Насколько я понимаю, Вам нужно сделать как бы прилипающий блок внутри статически расположенного блока. Если да, то вот примерное решение

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того, какая нужна поддержка
Если Ие, и всякая шушера не нужна, то вот вам вариант position: sticky;

```
.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZPQEG

если нет, то только js.
Вот, самый простой вариант, с установкой top

```
var $aside = $('.aside'),
    $main_fixed = $('.fixed'),
    aside_fixed_height = $aside.outerHeight(true) - $main_fixed.outerHeight(true),
    main_fixed_position_top = $aside.position().top,
    this_top = 0,
    this_top_end = 0;

$(window)
  .resize(function(){
    aside_fixed_height = $aside.outerHeight(true) - $main_fixed.outerHeight(true),
    main_fixed_position_top = $aside.position().top;
  })
  .scroll(function(){
    this_top = $(this).scrollTop();

    this_top_end = this_top - main_fixed_position_top;

    if(this_top_end < 0) {
      this_top_end = 0;
    }
    if(this_top_end > aside_fixed_height) {
      this_top_end = aside_fixed_height;
    }

    $main_fixed.css( 'top', this_top_end);
  });
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyqOwN